# use percentage with c#

Tags: c#, math, probability

I would like to run **3** scenarios. The first has **80%** which returns `IsRandom = false` the other two have **10%** each for `Group` `"A"` or `Group` `"B"`.

Here is **my code:**

```
Random randomGen = new Random();

...

int clickPercentage = randomGen.Next(100);

if (clickPercentage <= 20 / 2)
{ 
    return new RandomGroup {IsRandom = true, Group = "A"};
}
else if (clickPercentage <= 20)
{
    return new RandomGroup { IsRandom = true, Group = "B" };
}
else
{
    return new RandomGroup { IsRandom = false };
}
```

Is it *correct* (does it provide **10%** : **10%** : **80%** distribution)?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are you getting an unexpected result? There's not a whole lot to work here with. Please define whatever problem you have.

Comment: is the probability calc correct?

Comment: ah? it should have 10% probability

Comment: It's *roughly correct* (**11% : 10% : 79%**): from `[0..10]` (**11%**) for the first option, `(10..20]` (**10%**)for the second option, `(20..100)`  (**79%**) for the last ption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your distrubution is only *roughly* correct: **11%** vs. **10%** vs. **79%**. Note, that

- 1st option corresponds to `[0..10]` - **11%** probability (*both* borders are *included*)
- 2nd option corresponds to `(10..20]` - **10%** probability (one border is included, the other is excluded)
- The last option corresponds to `(20..100)` - **79%** probability (*both* borders are *excluded*)

If you insist on **10%** vs. **10%** vs. **80%** distribution put it as (your code corrected):

```
int clickPercentage = randomGen.Next(100);

if (clickPercentage < 10)
{ 
    return new RandomGroup {IsRandom = true, Group = "A"};
}
else if (clickPercentage < 20)
{
    return new RandomGroup { IsRandom = true, Group = "B" };
}
else
{
    return new RandomGroup { IsRandom = false };
}
```

Please, note `<` instead of `<=` (remember, that lower border `0` will be *included* when higher border `100` will be *exluded*)

You can simplify the code a bit with a help of turnary operator:

```
int clickPercentage = randomGen.Next(100);

return clickPercentage < 20 
  ? new RandomGroup() {IsRandom = true, Group = clickPercentage < 10 ? "A" : "B"} 
  : new RandomGroup { IsRandom = false };
```

**Edit:** To get rid of *Resharper's complains* you can drop `else`s which are *redundant*:

```
int clickPercentage = randomGen.Next(100);

if (clickPercentage < 10)
  return new RandomGroup {IsRandom = true, Group = "A"};
if (clickPercentage < 20)
  return new RandomGroup { IsRandom = true, Group = "B" };

return new RandomGroup { IsRandom = false };
```

Comment: does randomGen.Next(100); means actually [0,100] (both borders are inclusive), sir?

Comment: @snr: The actual range for `andomGen.Next(100);` is `[0..99]` or `[0..100)`, note that `100` is excluded

Comment: thanks. for some reason re sharper tells me redundant else keyword. not sure why...

Comment: elad: `else` is really *redundant*, since code *after* `else` is *unreachable*: you can drop `else {return new RandomGroup { IsRandom = false };}` and put just `return new RandomGroup { IsRandom = false };`

Comment: it says redundant on the else if as well...

Comment: @elad: since you return from `if`, `else if` can be changed into just `if`. See my edit, please

Comment: now it complains about the second if "convert to return statement" :)

Comment: @elad: it advises you to use *turnary operator* `? : ` instead of `if`: please, see how to do it in my code above -  "You can simplify the code a bit with a help of turnary operator:"

Answer (score 1):

This

```
randomGen.Next(100);
```

returns a value between 0 and 99. So you need to either change the `<=` to `<` in your equality tests, or use `randomGen.Next(1, 101)` which will return a value within 1 and 100.

The former is probably better from an ease-of-understanding perspective, but really it's a matter of taste.

The division operation here is unnecessary:

```
if (clickPercentage <=20/2)
```

Simply use `clickPercentage < 10`

Similarly, use `else if (clickPercentage < 20)`

The way you instantiate `RandomGroup` in your else statement could be an issue depending on how the `Group` property is defined